# Show that $\mathscr{L}\{f\}(s)=\frac{1}{s+3} \quad \text{when}f(x)=e^{-3x}$

Tags: laplace-transform

### Problem

Functions $f:[0,\infty[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ laplace transform, value at point $s > 0$ is defined with formula:

$$ \mathscr{L}\{f\}(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t)dt $$

Show that  $$\mathscr{L}\{f\}(s)=\frac{1}{s+3} \quad \text{when }f(x)=e^{-3x}$$

Problem is I don't even understand what I am supposed to do here? If someone could give hint in the right direction that how I should begin solving this that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're supposed to evaluate $$\int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{-3t}dt.$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, solving a more general problem:

$$\text{F}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{s}\right):=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\exp\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}:=\int_0^\infty\exp\left(\text{n}\cdot x\right)\cdot e^{-\text{s} x}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Substitute $\text{u}:=\left(\text{n}-\text{s}\right)\cdot x$:

$$\text{F}_{\space\text{n}}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{1}{\text{n}-\text{s}}\cdot\lim_{\text{p}\to\infty}\int_0^{\left(\text{n}-\text{s}\right)\cdot\text{p}}\exp\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{n}-\text{s}}\cdot\lim_{\text{p}\to\infty}\left[\exp\left(\text{u}\right)\right]_0^{\left(\text{n}-\text{s}\right)\cdot\text{p}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{n}-\text{s}}\cdot\lim_{\text{p}\to\infty}\left(\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-\text{s}\right)\cdot\text{p}\right)-\exp\left(0\right)\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{n}-\text{s}}\cdot\lim_{\text{p}\to\infty}\left(\exp\left(\left(\text{n}-\text{s}\right)\cdot\text{p}\right)-1\right)\tag2$$

> Now, what happends to the limit when:
>
> $$\Re\left(\text{n}\right)<\Re\left(\text{s}\right)\tag3$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)
&=& \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(t) \ \mathrm dt \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}e^{-3t} \ \mathrm dt \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(s+3)t} \ \mathrm dt \\
&=& \displaystyle \left[\frac{-1}{s+3} e^{-(s+3)t}\right]_{0}^{\infty} \\
&=& \displaystyle \left[0 - \frac{-1}{s+3}\right] \\
&=& \displaystyle \frac{1}{s+3} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\int\limits_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{at}e^{-st} \mathrm{d}t$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\int\limits_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{at-st} \mathrm{d}t$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\int\limits_{t=0}^{\infty}e^{(a-s)t} \mathrm{d}t$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\left[\frac{1}{a-s}e^{(a-s)t}\right]_{t=0}^{t=\infty}$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\frac{1}{a-s}\left[e^{(a-s)t}\right]_{t=0}^{t=\infty}$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\frac{1}{a-s}\left[\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} e^{(a-s)t}-e^{(a-s)0}\right]$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\frac{1}{a-s}\left[\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} e^{(a-s)t}-1\right]$$
Now we need to suppose that $a-s<0$ for the limit to exist (and to be $0$):
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\frac{1}{a-s}\left[0-1\right]$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=-\frac{1}{a-s}$$
$$\mathscr{L}\{e^{at}\}(s)=\frac{1}{s-a}$$

Comment: Notice that your statement about the limit, is not true for complex values for $n$ and $s$

Comment: @JanEerland Of course, the bigger, etc. relations are not defined for complex numbers. But as I see, you were taking care of the complex values.